# How to use Super() in Python 2.7 for multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, super

Using super in python 2.7 results in error code,

> TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: Note that Python 2 is deprecated and is no longer under support/development since 2020, so it shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: So when you copied and pasted the phrase `How to use Super() in Python 2.7 for multiple inheritance` into a search engine, and [looked over the various results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+use+Super()+in+Python+2.7+for+multiple+inheritance), what exactly confused you? How about when you copied and pasted the [error message](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=TypeError%3A+super()+takes+at+least+1+argument+(0+given))?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code can help in understanding how to use the super function for multiple inheritance in python 2.7,

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Class A")
        super(A, self).__init__()


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Class B")
        super(B, self).__init__()


class C(A, B):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Class C")
        super(C, self).__init__()


Cobj = C()
```

In Python 3, super function is a bit simplified and can be used as follows,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Class A")
        super().__init__()


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Class B")
        super().__init__()


class C(A, B):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Class C")
        super().__init__()


Cobj = C()
```

If you run the above code in python 2.7, you will get this error message,

> TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Most books assume python- 3.x is being used in all productions, which is not the case. So code style and patterns from 2.7 are still very relevant for developers.